# How to view full logs in Apps Script dashboard

Tags: debugging, logging, google-apps-script

The logs in my App Script dashboard are truncated; I can only see the last X log entries. I know the dashboard is supposed to be a simplified version, but is it possible to even get the full logs from the dashboard (or elsewhere) somehow?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Google Apps Script has three different logs which persist for different amounts of time and contain different levels of information.*

#### Further Information:

As per the Apps Script documentation:

> Apps Script provides three different mechanisms for logging:
>
> - The built-in Apps Script Logger, which is lightweight but persists only for a short time.
> - The Stackdriver Logging interface in the Developer Console, which provides logs that persist for many days after their creation.
> - The Stackdriver Error Reporting interface in the Developer Console, which collects and records errors that occur while your script is running.

#### How to view:

**Logger.log() :**

Logs created this way can be made by using the `Logger.log()` line in the script, and can be viewed by selecting View > Logs in the script editor.

**Stackdriver Logging:**

When you requre logging that persists for a longer time than per-run, Stackdrier logs are preferred. These are attached to the GCP project that is associated with the Apps Script project, and a simplified version can be found in the [Apps Script dashboard](https://script.google.com/home/executions). Exception logging can also be done via the Stackdriver logs.

**Stackdriver Error Reporting:**

You can view your Stackdriver error reports in the [GCP console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#viewing_stackdriver_logs_and_error_reports_in_the_google_cloud_platform_console).

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging)

  - [Basic Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#basic_logging)
  - [Stackdriver Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging)
  - [Exception Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#exception_logging)
  - [Stackdriver Error Reporting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_error_reporting)
  - [Logging Requirements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#logging_requirements)
- [Google Apps Script Class `Logger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger)